# Right hand sidebar code issue

Tags: css, sidebar

Hi not sure what im doing wrong with my css code?
Here is a screenshot of what i want my site to look like and here is what it looks like. I need the sidebar to look the same as the screenshot. Thanks for the help!

- [What my sidebar should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF9gh.png)
- [What is currently looks like](https://www.brierty.website/about-us/our-history/)

Comment: This is too broad — are you expecting someone to write a whole stylesheet for you?  Try doing it on your own, and if you encounter a *specific* problem, ask a *specific* question.

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. I suggest you to read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks  for the reply. I already wrote the code. The only thing i cant seem to resolve is how to separate the sidebar menu items horizontally each with their own border.

Comment: Then provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the relevant HTML and CSS you're using for the sidebar, and the part that you're having trouble with.  Don't expect people to visit your site and analyze your stylesheet just to find out how your sidebar is structured.  This is a volunteer site; if you make it burdensome to figure out what the exact question is, most people won't bother trying to answer.